# C# Get all return values from methods of a class

Tags: c#, methods, system.reflection

I have a `class` with a number of methods that `return` same `object` type. I want to all `return` values of all methods from that `class`. For example: I have class called Class1 with Method1, Method2 and MapActivity, each method1 and 2 has `switch` `case` returning certain enum values. I want to retrieve all that `return` values from both methods.

```
public static class Class1
    {

       public static string MapActivity(Human human, Activity activity)
        {
            switch (human)
            {
                case Human.Me:
                    return Method1(activity);
                case Human.Him:
                    return Method2(activity);
                default:
                    return "error";
            }
        }

       public enum Activity
        {
            Eat,
            Sleep,
            Game,
            Drink,
            Poop,
            Slack,
        }

        private static string Method1(Activity myActivity)
        {
            switch (myActivity)
            {
                case Activity.Eat:
                    return "one";
                case Activity.Sleep:
                    return "two";
                case Activity.Drink:
                    return "three";
                case Activity.Game:
                    return "four";
                case Activity.Poop:
                    return "five";
                case Activity.Eat:
                    return "six";
                default:
                    return "error";
            }
        }

        private static string Method2(Activity hisActivity)
        {
            switch (hisActivity)
            {
                case Activity.Eat:
                    return "seven";
                case Activity.Sleep:
                    return "eight";
                case Activity.Drink:
                    return "nine";
                case Activity.Slack:
                    return "ten";
                case Activity.Poop:
                    return "eleven";
                case Activity.Game:
                    return "twelve";
                default:
                    return "error";
            }
        }
}

public class Class2
{
    public void CheckReturnValues()
    {
        //this is where i want to do my thing
        //get all private methods from Class1
        //get all return values from those methods
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of `["one", "two", "three", ...]`?

Comment: yes, correct...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reflection, Get return value from a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405568/reflection-get-return-value-from-a-method)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you trying to do some testing?

Comment: Why do you want to do it? what is your goal?

Comment: I'm trying to check all return values exist in database, some sort of validation

Comment: First of all, your method return type is Int and you are returning string from switch case. What is the end result is still unclear. Perhaps can you provide little more description?

Comment: It looks like these particular methods (once all compile errors have been fixed) expect a limited number of input values. Can you just iterate over the possible input values and check the result?

Comment: Imagine a method `public static string AddOne(string input) => input + "1";`. "All (possible) return values" would be all possible `string` values. Which are a lot. In your case, the methods are "easy" and you can "easily" see, that there are only a few possible return values. But for a compiler or code analyzer, it's not so easy. It's basically the "halting problem".

Comment: Perhaps I'm not explaining things right, edited...

Comment: If you can explain your problem more deeply, maybe we could solve your problem.

Comment: Now this is something we can work on :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your code is not compilable - you are returning string instead of int and you have duplicate case values in the switch.

Secondly. You don't want to do that at all. The only way you can achieve this is through parsing the body of the method (and maybe also another parts of the code). But this works under certain conditons only - you have to use only local or static values, etc. You will never be able to get any dynamic value unless you'll compile and run the code.

You can solve your problem if you restrict the switch variable to some kind of finite enumeration. In this case, you are able to iterate through the enumeration, call the methods with each value of the enumeration and then you will get all possible return values. If this is your case, looping through the enumeration values can be made like this:

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foos));
```

or in typed version:

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foos)).Cast<Foos>();
```

And then you just call the method inside the loop:

```
var results = new List<string>();
foreach (Foos val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foos)).Cast<Foos>())
{
   results.Add(Class1.Method1(val));
}
```

The same goes for Method2.

---

After editing the question the code should be like this:

```
var myActivities = new List<string>();
var hisActivities = new List<string>();
foreach (Activity activity in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Activity)).Cast<Activity>())
{
   myActivities.Add(Class1.Method1(activity));
   hisActivities.Add(Class1.Method2(activity));
}
```

Then you will have two lists of my/his activities and you can check if the code is matching your database values like this:

```
bool myActivitiesHasError = myActivities.Any(x => x == "error")
bool hisActivitiesHasError = hisActivities.Any(x => x == "error")
```

Or you can check the value just inside the loop:

```
bool myActivitiesHasError = false;
bool hisActivitiesHasError = false;
foreach (Activity activity in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Activity)).Cast<Activity>())
{
   if (myActivities.Add(Class1.Method1(activity)) == "error") myActivitiesHasError = true;
   if (hisActivities.Add(Class1.Method2(activity)) == "error") hisActivitiesHasError = true;
}
```

To cover the whole question. If you want to access private methods of the class, then you have to use the reflection.

```
MethodInfo method1 = typeof(Class1).GetMethod("Method1", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
MethodInfo method2 = typeof(Class1).GetMethod("Method2", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
foreach (Activity activity in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Activity)).Cast<Activity>())
{
    method1.Invoke(null, activity);
    method2.Invoke(null, activity);
}
```

Just merge the last code (with the reflection) with the previous ones...it depends on what you want to do exactly with the output.

You should also use some kind of variable for the "error" value and then use it in the condition statements:

```
private static string ErrorValue = "error";
```

Comment: ... All of which you'll want to do in a _UnitTest_, not production code.

Comment: I disagree...there are some situations where this kind of code can be useful even in production code. Of course, you are relying on the correctness of the enumeration itself, so you have to be careful there. It all depends on what you are trying to achieve and why.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. If you have a finite set of inputs, you'd expect a finite set of outputs. Otherwise the function is not deterministic. And that would be bad. Mind: we are talking about getting _all_ results.

Comment: taking shape now, but it's returning Activity. I want "one,two,three,four" values.

Comment: I have edited it...you should now get list of strings.

Comment: almost there, thanks, but what if one of the methods has more than one parameter? like, if method2 has two parameters

Comment: @april - this answer shows you the general approach: *call the method(s) with all possible inputs to get all possible outputs*. This works, if you have a rather small set of possible inputs. If a method for example has one boolean parameter, you need to try the two possible inputs `true` and `false` to get the possible outputs. If the method has two boolean inputs, you need to try all **four** (2²) possibilities: `true, true`, `true, false`, `false, true` and `false, false`. If you have three boolean parameters, there are **eight** (2³) possible combinations. Now "simply" apply that to enums.